# How do I execute a Tk-Canvas function stored as a reference in a hash table?

Tags: perl, reference, tk-toolkit

I am trying to execute a Tk-function stored as a reference to a function in a hash table. In the very simplified example below, the code should draw a big red dot (i.e. do what line 14 does). I can't make a valid reference to createOval(), neither with $w-> in the hash table, nor with it moved down to line 13. I have googled for this high and low, but to no avail. What am I missing?

If I treat $w->... as a reference, the error message is "wrong number of args: ..." and if I stuff \& in front of $w in line 10: "Not a CODE reference at a11.pl line 9."

This is dead easy to do in Python: just stuff w.create_oval into the dictionary and it works.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;
my $w = $mw->Canvas(-width => 1200, -height => 800);
$w->pack;

my %xfun = (
    'b' => $w->createOval
);

$xfun{'b'}(200, 200, 250, 250, -fill=>'red');
#$w->createOval(200, 200, 250, 250, -fill=>'red');

MainLoop;
```

Comment: reinierpost, I am still confused :(

Comment: @reinierpost That's completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;
my $w = $mw->Canvas(-width => 1200, -height => 800);
$w->pack;

my %xfun = (
    b => sub { $w->createOval(@_); },
);

$xfun{b}->(200, 200, 250, 250, -fill=>'red');

MainLoop;
```

**Note:**

I assumed that your original call:

```
$xfun{'b'}(200, 200, 250, 250, -fill=>'red');
```

did not work because it missed the object `$w` as first arg, but when I 
tried passing `$w` explicitly as the first argument:

```
$xfun{'b'}($w, 200, 200, 250, 250, -fill=>'red');
```

it still did not work.. I got error:

```
wrong # args: should be ".canvas create oval coords ?arg arg ...?"
```

Comment: Great. Just like the OP I also googled and fiddled around with `\ `, `&`, `{`, and `}` and any combination of them with no result. Using a closure is the trick. I verified with `IO::File` and `$fh->print` instead of `Tk` because I haven't installed the latter.

Comment: @PerlDog Yes, I was (and am still) a little bit confused about this behavior :)

Comment: Excellent! I had fiddled around with the sub { but my imagination didn't get round to add (@_)! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> If I treat $w->... as a reference, the error message is "wrong number of args: ..."

I don't know what you mean by "treat as a reference".

Your code doesn't work as written because `$w->createOval` is a method call without arguments, same as `$w->createOval()`.

With `\&$w->createOval` it parses as `\((&$w)->createOval)`, which is (mostly) the same as `\($w->(@_)->createOval)`:

- treat `$w` as a code reference and call it with the current parameter list, `@_` (this is where your error occurs because `$w` is actually an object)
- take the return value and call the `createOval` method on it
- take a reference to the return value of `createOval`

You can get a reference to the `createOval` sub using [`$w->can('createOval')`](https://metacpan.org/pod/UNIVERSAL), but that doesn't help you because that's just the function (without the object). To call it, you'd have to explicitly pass in `$w` as the first argument (this happens implicitly in method calls):

```
my %xfun = (
    'b' => $w->can('createOval'),
);

$xfun{'b'}($w, 200, 200, 250, 250, -fill=>'red');
```

---

The most direct solution is `b => sub { $w->createOval(@_) }`, i.e. wrap the method call in a proxy sub that forwards its arguments.

Comment: Yes, this good.. I also finally found that the hash definition actually called `createOval` and not returned a code ref. But I was not able to get the coderef correctly even when using `\&{"Tk::Canvas::createOval"}`

Comment: Great too! Thanks!

Comment: @HåkonHægland That can be written as `\&Tk::Canvas::createOval`, which should work assuming `Tk::Canvas` is the correct package (the `$w->can('createOval')` method takes inheritance into account) and you pass $w as the first argument.